# Shortcut for running a single line of code in R

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio, shortcut

Does anyone know how I could create a keyboard shortcut or something similar to run a single line of diagnostic code in R Studio?  i.e. if I wanted to do something simple, like checking the dimensions of a data frame, but I wanted to do it a lot throughout the day and didn't want to be continually typing dim(data), how could I get dim(data) into a keyboard shortcut or some other quick easy way to call that single line of code?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? That might have definable keyboard shortcuts... What operating system?

Comment: Yes, I'm using R Studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R itself can’d do that. Your editor may be able to, though (I know that Vim + Vim-R can do something like this).

What you can do in R is [bind a function to an active binding](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bindenv.html). That way, whenever you invoke the binding, it executes your piece of code. To illustrate:

```
makeActiveBinding('x', function () dim(data), globalenv())
```

Now whenever you enter `x` in the R console, it executes `dim(data)`.

Answer (score 3):

The plain R terminal has a reverse incremental search function to make repetitive things easy. Hit Ctrl-R and start typing, it will match against your history. In this example, I've typed "di" and its enough to find the last "dim" call I did:

```
> x=matrix(1:12,3,4)
> dim(x)
[1] 3 4
> y=runif(100)
> dim(x)
[1] 3 4
# hit Ctrl-R at the prompt and type "d"... "i"....
(reverse-i-search)`di': dim(x)
```

I can hit return now, and it will do `dim(x)` for me. In fact it found it at the "d" because there was nothing else starting with a "d!" in the history.

There's a similar things in Emacs-ESS but I don't suppose you are using that. I don't know if this is implemented in RStudio, StatET, Architect, RCmdr or any of the other R interfaces that you might be using. I think RStudio might have a quick history search.

Comment: In fact the R terminal simply uses the readlines API so it can be configured via `.inputrc`. I have up- and down keys bound so that they [incrementally search the history](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/the-most-important-command-line-tip-incremental-history-searching-with-inputrc/). This makes Ctr-R unnecessary in most cases. Just type the start of the command and use arrow-up to complete the command.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the snippet feature in RStudio (Tools -> Global Options... brings up the menu below).  You can then add a snippet such as the code chunk below.

```
snippet d
   dim(data)
```

Once the snippet is saved you can type the `d` (or whatever other string you defined after `snippet`). Then press tab and RStudio will give you the option to replace the shortcut string with the code listed in the snippet (here `dim(data)`).

There might be other options but for something as simple as a `dim` statement. There would likely be more effort than value add.

[image]

Comment: This only works inside the code editor window, not on the R console, right? In that case I think it’s useless for OP.

Comment: true. I do think the snippet feature is limited to the editor.